# tic tac toe using methods java

Tags: java, tic-tac-toe

the code is supposed to play tictactoe, but theres an exception in the print game board method, out of bounds exception, and i cant figure out why. if anyone knows how to avoid that exception i would appreciate advice. this is what i have so far:

```
 static char arrayList[][] = {{0,1,2},{0,1,2}};
 static Scanner input;
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 // Only one scanner!!!
 input = new Scanner(System.in);
 while (true) { // TTT 4 forever!
 printGameBoard();
 userInput();
 if (checkForWin('X')) {
 System.out.println("Congrats, you won!");
 break;
 }
 if (checkForStale()) {
 printGameBoard();
 System.out.println("Tie!");
 break;
 }
 computerTurn();
 if (checkForWin('O')) {
 System.out.println("All hail the future overlords!");
 break;
 }
 if (checkForStale()) {
 System.out.println("Tie!");
 break;
 }
 }
 }
 static void printGameBoard() {
 System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
 System.out.println("| " + arrayList[0][0] + " | " + arrayList[0][1] + " | " + arrayList[0][2]
 + " |");
 System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
 System.out.println("| " + arrayList[1][0] + " | " + arrayList[1][1] + " | " + arrayList[1][2]
 + " |");
 System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
 System.out.println("| " + arrayList[2][0] + " | " + arrayList[2][1] + " | " + arrayList[2][2]
 + " |");
 System.out.println("+---+---+---+");
 }
 static void userInput() {
 System.out.print("Please enter the board number:");
 int place = input.nextInt();
// Note to self: check user input for sanity here!
 if (checkForSanity(place)) {
 placeOnBoard(place, 'X');
 System.out.println("Ok...");
 printGameBoard();
 } else {
 System.out.println("Wrong move!");
 }
 }
 static void computerTurn() {
 boolean placed = false;
 while (!placed) {
 // Randomly choose a place
 int place = (int) (1 + (Math.random() * 8));
 // Check if sane
 if (checkForSanity(place)) {
 placeOnBoard(place, 'O');
 placed = true;
 }
 }
 printGameBoard();
 }
 static boolean checkForWin(char piece) {
 if ((arrayList[0][0] == piece) && (arrayList[0][1] == piece) && (arrayList[0][2] == piece))
 return true;
 if ((arrayList[1][0] == piece) && (arrayList[1][1] == piece) && (arrayList[1][2] == piece))
 return true;
 if ((arrayList[2][0] == piece) && (arrayList[2][1] == piece) && (arrayList[2][2] == piece))
 return true;
 if ((arrayList[0][0] == piece) && (arrayList[1][0] == piece) && (arrayList[2][0] == piece))
 return true;
 if ((arrayList[0][1] == piece) && (arrayList[1][1] == piece) && (arrayList[2][1] == piece))
 return true;
 if ((arrayList[0][2] == piece) && (arrayList[1][2] == piece) && (arrayList[2][2] == piece))
 return true;
 if ((arrayList[0][0] == piece) && (arrayList[1][1] == piece) && (arrayList[2][2] == piece))
 return true;
 if ((arrayList[0][2] == piece) && (arrayList[1][1] == piece) && (arrayList[2][0] == piece))
 return true;
 return false;
 }
 static boolean checkForStale() {
 if ((arrayList[0][0] != ' ') && (arrayList[0][1] != ' ') && (arrayList[0][2] != ' ')
 && (arrayList[1][0] != ' ') && (arrayList[1][1] != ' ') && (arrayList[1][2] != ' ')
 && (arrayList[2][0] != ' ') && (arrayList[2][1] != ' ') && (arrayList[2][2] != ' '))
 return true;
 return false;
 }
 static void placeOnBoard(int place, char piece) {
 if (place == 1)
 arrayList[0][0] = piece;
 else if (place == 2)
 arrayList[0][1] = piece;
 else if (place == 3)
 arrayList[0][2] = piece;
 else if (place == 4)
 arrayList[1][0] = piece;
 else if (place == 5)
 arrayList[1][1] = piece;
 else if (place == 6)
 arrayList[1][2] = piece;
 else if (place == 7)
 arrayList[2][0] = piece;
 else if (place == 8)
 arrayList[2][1] = piece;
 else if (place == 9)
 arrayList[2][2] = piece;
 }
 static boolean checkForSanity(int place) {
 boolean sane = false;
 if ((place == 1) && (arrayList[0][0] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 2) && (arrayList[0][1] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 3) && (arrayList[0][2] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 4) && (arrayList[1][0] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 5) && (arrayList[1][1] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 6) && (arrayList[1][2] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 7) && (arrayList[2][0] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 8) && (arrayList[2][1] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 else if ((place == 9) && (arrayList[2][2] == ' '))
 sane = true;
 return sane;
 }
 static boolean checkForSanity(int row, int col) {
 return true;
 }
}
```

`

Comment: and what is that exception?

Answer (score 2):

I believe that the problem is with your initialization of arrayList.  You have it defined with 2 rows, and 3 columns.  Also you are initializing it to the integers 0, 1, 2, not the characters '0', '1', '2', so when printing it, it's going to print control characters.

I'd suggest creating it like:

```
char[][] arrayList = new char[3][3];
```

this will leave you with an empty board (all cells will be null.

Answer (score 2):

Check out the line

```
 static char arrayList[][] = {{0,1,2},{0,1,2}};
```

you only declare a 2x3 array. Try adding one more row to make it a 3x3.

```
tatic char arrayList[][] = {{0,1,2},{0,1,2},{0,1,2}};
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are out of bounds with your array dimensions. In particular your first dimension can only be a 0 or 1, and your second dimension can be a 0, 1, or 2.

Given this:

```
static char arrayList[][] = {{0,1,2},{0,1,2}};
```

This would be invalid:

```
arrayList[2][0]
```